# How do I query date ranges in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

According to the Rails guides, this is how would you query with ranges:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#range-types

```
## All Events on a given date
Event.where("dates @> ?::date", Date.new(2014, 2, 12))
```

But how do I get all the events within a daterange?

I know I can do this:

```
Event.where("dates && daterange(?, ?)", date1, date2)
```

But this daterange will default to use '[)' as the bounds. Is there a way to supply a range, instead of two dates, so that the actual bounds are taken in consideration automatically?

Notice that these are different:

```
date1..date2  !=   date1...date2
```

So far I am doing this:

```
if dates.exclude_end?
  Event.where("dates && daterange(?, ?, '[)')", dates.begin, dates.end)
else
  Event.where("dates && daterange(?, ?, '[]')", dates.begin, dates.end)
end
```

But is there a better way? I would love something as this:

```
Event.where("dates && ?::daterange)", dates)
```

EDIT:

In my case, the `dates` is a daterange.

```
[6] pry(main)> Reservation.where(dates:     Date.current..4.days.from_now.to_date).explain

Reservation Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE ("reservations"."dates" BETWEEN $1 AND $2)  [["dates", Mon, 30 Jan 2017], ["dates", Fri, 03 Feb 2017]]

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed range literal: "2017-01-30"
```

Comment: Does something like `Event.where(date: date1...date2)` not work for your situation?

Comment: No. In my case the dates column is a daterange, not a date. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rangetypes.html

Comment: I pasted the output for your query in the 'Edit' section of the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. I'm afraid I have never worked with the daterange datatype in PG, but hopefully someone here has :)

Comment: Hi, apologies if this is a stupid question but is the column `dates` in `reservations` a date or datetime object?  According to your schema?

Comment: `daterange` is a PostgreSQL specific type and as such, it is not very well supported in ORMs. Your `if` logic seems solid; maybe you could simplify more, like `Event.where("dates && daterange(?, ?, ?)", dates.begin, dates.end, dates.exclude_end? ? '[)' : '[]')` -- (I'm not very familiar with ruby syntax, so I just hope the `dates.exclude_end? ? ... : ...` part is valid.)

Comment: @SteveTurczyn It's a daterange.

Comment: @pozs That's a very good solution. Want to make an answer out of it so that I mark it the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` logic seems solid. Maybe you could simplify it more, like

```
Event.where("dates && daterange(?, ?, ?)",
            dates.begin, dates.end, dates.exclude_end? ? '[)' : '[]')
```

This way, all your variables are bound parameters & don't have to use 2 distinct queries.

`daterange` is a PostgreSQL specific type and as such, it is not very well supported in ORMs. (Also, it seems that ActiveRecord binds ranges as `BETWEEN` expressions, so you can't bind them as values).